# Cron tabs on windows using EasyPhp

Tags: windows, cron, easyphp

Is it possible to make a custom cron tab which just request a page ?

Every 5 minutes ?

I dont figure how to do that..

Is this almost possible ?

THanks

Answer (score -1):

Look into [PyCron](http://www.kalab.com/freeware/pycron/pycron.htm) or make an account on [000WebHost](http://000webhost.com), upload your file there, and add a cron job ni the User CP since you only need for it to run every 5 min (I highly recommend the latter if your computer's not constantly running).

Comment: thanks, but what can i execute to go to a web local page using pycron ? Cannot fin any help

Comment: @user1965147 What do you mean by a web local page?

Comment: He's asking if there's a way to run a cron job on a __local__ machine, not on a shared hosting.